# Incompatibilidad de etiqueta "ng-select2 " con evento "change"

Tags: javascript, angular7, html-select

Necesito llenar un formulario, en el cual el primer "input" es de tipo "select" cuyas opciones vienen de una base de datos, (cientos de ellos), por lo que si o si necesito la función auto completar, y una vez seleccionado ese dato, con una función habilitaré las opciones del campo siguiente. El proyecto esta siendo desarrollado para el front con Angular7, y el back es laravel 5.8 (creo que este dato es irrelevante en este caso), lo mas cómodo que encontré para autocompletar en Angular7 es una etiqueta "ng-select2", que funciona de maravilla, pero ignora el evento (change), no así el evento (click), pero click no me sirve. Alguien sabe como debo hacer para interpretar el change en este caso? Me recomiendan otro forma de hacerlo? Adjunto los códigos. Con la salvedad que la función que se ejecuta ante el evento change , funciona correctamente con la etiqueta "select" (la ya conocida) y que a la consulta que genero con este dato la puedo realizar ya sea recibiendo o no la variable $event. Desde muchas gracias.  Saludos!!. 
Aqui va el component.html

```
 <!--Archivo .component.html-->  <ng-select2 name="modelo" #modelo="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="registro.lote" [width]="420" (change)="funcion_menu_modelo($event)">
                                    <option *ngFor="let option of options" >
                                       {{option.modelo}}
                                    </option>
                            </ng-select2>
```

Y a continuación la función correspondiente en el archivo .component.ts

```
     /*funcion desde el archivo component.ts*/funcion_menu_modelo($event){



              this._registroService.menu_lotes(this.registro.modelo).subscribe(

              response=>{

                if(response.status=='success'){
                 this.options_lot=response.lotes;

              }else{
                this.status_options_lot='error'; 
              }

            },
              error=>{
                console.log(<any>error);
                 this.status_options_lot='error';

              } 

           );
  }
```

Comment: intenta  `<option *ngFor="let option of options | async" > `

Comment: Gracias. Te comento, tu solución me devuelve el siguiente error por consola: 
    "RegistroNewComponent.html:28 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],(esto repetido la cantidad de registros que tengo)" me falto importar algo?.

Comment: puedes agregar que tiene options probablemente no tiene el formato correcto

Comment: Creo que si `option` no es una `Promise` no necesita usar `async` para pintar el contenido cuando se resuelva o actualice el contenido de la misma.

Comment: investigue sobre el async, y si bien sirve para guardar el estado anterior, sigo con el problema que al querer usar el evento (change) dentro de la etiqueta ng-select2, esta lo ignora.